# Why does the "An edit has been made to this post" appear above the ads?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, edits

I was sitting on a post on Stack Overflow, and due to my having less than 200 rep, I was staring at an ad. The post, however, was edited, and the bar popped up--above the ad, barely noticeable. Can this bar be moved to be below the ads?

Comment: F5 and the problem is gone.

Comment: On other sites it's usually the other way around.. Ad banners popping over the actual content.. That would be a valid reason to complain.

Comment: @MichalKlouda On SO the bar is barely visible in its drab colors next to an obnoxiously-colored ad. Sorry to nitpick.